# SQL server use case in order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of the column in my table like this:

```
Symbol  
586fast                
urgent         
243late  
296fast  
122late   
155fast
```

I need urgent in first then records with fast then records with late like this:

```
urgent  
586fast  
296fast  
155fast  
243late   
122late
```

I am getting urgent in first row by:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN substring(Symbol, len(Symbol) - 2, 3) = 'ent'THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

After that it is order by number in records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said you are on 2005 you could do something like this.

```
order by case 
    when Symbol = 'urgent' then 1
    when Symbol like '%fast' then 2
    when Symbol like '%late' then 3
    else 4 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('urgent', Symbol) > 0 THEN 1 
              WHEN CHARINDEX('fast', Symbol) > 0 THEN 2 
              WHEN CHARINDEX('late', Symbol) > 0 THEN 3
              ELSE 4 
         END
```

Comment: I am using 2005 server

Comment: Dear, INSTR doesn't exist in Sql Server.